# Jackson: using builder with nondefault constructor

Tags: xml, jackson, deserialization, builder

I have the following class:

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Transaction.Builder.class)
public final class Transaction {

    @JacksonXmlText
    private final TransactionType transactionType;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private final boolean transactionAllowed;

    private Transaction(Builder builder) {
        transactionType = builder.transactionType;
        transactionAllowed = builder.transactionAllowed;
    }

    public static final class Builder {
        private final TransactionType transactionType;
        private boolean transactionAllowed;

        public Builder(TransactionType transactionType) {
            this.transactionType = transactionType;
        }

        public Builder withTransactionAllowed() {
            transactionAllowed = true;
            return this;
        }

        public Transaction build() {
            return new Transaction(this);
        }
    }
}
```

`TransactionType` is a simple enum:

```
public enum TransactionType {
    PU,
    CV;
}
```

When I create a new Transaction instance and serialize it using Jackson mapper I get the following xml:

```
<transaction transactionAllowed="true">PU</transaction>
```

The problem is that I cannot deserialize it. I get the following exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class Transaction$Builder]
```

If I put @JsonCreator on the Builder constructor like this:

```
@JsonCreator
public Builder(TransactionType transactionType) {
    this.transactionType = transactionType;
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not construct
instance of Transaction from String value 'transactionAllowed': value not one of
declared Enum instance names: [PU, CV]
```

If I then put @JsonProperty on the constructor parameter like this:

```
@JsonCreator
public Builder(@JsonProperty TransactionType transactionType) {
    this.transactionType = transactionType;
}
```

I get another error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Could not find creator
property with name '' (in class Transaction$Builder)
```

Any ideas how to get around this?

Answer (score -1):

After all I made it work writing this builder:

```
public static final class Builder {
    @JacksonXmlText
    private final TransactionType transactionType;
    private boolean transactionAllowed;

    @JsonCreator
    public Builder(@JsonProperty(" ") TransactionType transactionType) {
        this.transactionType = transactionType;
    }

    public Builder withTransactionAllowed() {
        transactionAllowed = true;
        return this;
    }

    public Transaction build() {
        return new Transaction(this);
    }
}
```

Notice that the value of @JsonProperty is not empty, it can actually be any value except for an empty string. I don't believe this is the best solution ever but it works. Yet I won't accept my own answer as there is probably a better solution.

Comment: For "@JsonProperty", you should fill in the name of the property, which should be "transactionType" in your case. Json exceptions will be thrown if you have more than one parameters in your Builder constructor if you leave "@JsonProperty" blank.